# Animate title mask from location a to b in Adobe Premiere CC 2017

Tags: premiere, mask, cc-2017

I am very new to Adobe Premiere, but have worked with Final Cut Pro a long time ago, so you can say, I understand the basics.

I am attempting to create a "fancy" lyrics video. Fancy in the sense that the lyric text (a Title in Adobe Premiere) gets filled with a different a colour in sync with the artist singing the song.

I am attempting to achieve this with a mask (solid colour) placed over the title, but I do not know how I can animate the mask from location A to location B. I have created a [Screencast](https://www.screencast.com/t/flnpbmU4zj) to show where I'm stuck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use keyframes instead of tracking. You can find them here:
[image]
For better understanding of how they work, [read](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/setting-selecting-deleting-keyframes.html) about them, or watch the [video](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/how-to/aftereffects-add-adjust-keyframes-cc.html).
Long story short, you need to create keyframe in the first place, where motion starts. After that you need to have keyframe in every place, where is key place of position. If you will just move the mask, after creating first keyframe, other ones will be created automaticly, after you move mask.

To create keyframe, press on the middle round button, in the place highlighted on screenshot above.

Comment: Thanks @Shultc. I'll have a read and try and do what you've suggested when I get back home this evening.

Comment: it worked flawlessly, thank you very much! Is there an easy way I can get a hold of my Mask 1 shape? Right now I'm having to use the mouse between inserting each frame

Comment: I didn't really understood your question.... But you didn't need to make keyframe every frame. Only in start and end positions of the movement. Try to play around with it, to understand it better. Like creating one keyframe in one place, and another keyframe in another place after about 10 seconds. And watch movement between. There also are different types of keyframes and graphs, to adjust them.... But I don't think you need it in your case. Good luck!